# Why is there a selectedOptions property and not a selectedOption instead?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the `select`'s property `selectedOptions` returns an `HTMLCollection` and not just one `HTMLOptionElement` instead? I mean (corret me if I am wrong), `select` will always have only **one** selected option, so everytime I use `selectedOptions` to get the selected option I must write `select.selectedOptions[0]`.

It is not a problem at all, but... Why must it returns an array?

Example:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#example-select')
select.addEventListener('change', () => console.log(select.selectedOptions[0].value))
```

```html
<select name="example-select" id="example-select">
  <option value hidden>-- Choose --</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I would assume that having one property for both single and mulit select fields is better than switching between two properties in your JS code

Comment: `select will always have only one selected option` this is not the case when using a `select multiple` element. The same methods apply to both `select` instances, hence the pluralised property name and return of a collection.

Comment: The select element does have a [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple) attribute. If yours only has one value, you should be able to just use `selectElement.value`.

Comment: The assumption that "select will only have one selected option" is plain wrong; see [`<select multiple>`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#multiple).

Comment: I didn't know about `multiple` attribute and its use. Now it makes sense for me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

The `selectedOptions` returns an HTML collection. It is not `selectedOption` because in certain situations it can also return multiple items, HTML allows for multi-select dropdowns where users can select multiple.